# Is there a multi-month view for kendo-ui Scheduler?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I needed to display an entire year or a multiple month view because we only have 1 or 2 events a month.

Is it possible to do this in kendo-ui Scheduler?

I know there is a multiple day view extension, but is there something similar for months?

```
var ThreeDayView = kendo.ui.MultiDayView.extend({
```

Comment: no there is not built in unless you want to spend time on writing a custom one

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For such scenario you can use the timelineMonth [view type](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-views.type) of the control as for example it is use in this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline). There is no other multi-month view.